# Creating an out of sample forecast in Python based on ARIMA model built on train and test data

Tags: python, prediction, sample, arima, forecast

I've developed an ARIMA model in Python using the **statsmodels.tsa.arima.model** package.  The series is split into **train** and **test** series.

The ARIMA model has been built using the following code and the model is then used to forecast over the test period so as to allow comparison:

```
train_size = int(len(X) * 0.66)
train, test = X[0:train_size], X[train_size:]
history = [x for x in train]
predictions = list()
for t in range(len(test)):
    model = ARIMA(history, order=1,0,1)
    model_fit = model.fit()
    yhat = model_fit.forecast()[0]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    history.append(test[t])
```

How would I add to the above code to create a one-day out-of-sample forecast?  That is a one-day forecast that takes into account the observed values in the **test** dataset/creates a prediction one day after the **test** period ends.

I've tried different attempts but none give the required solution (e.g. I can create a one-day forecast for immediately after the **train** period).

I'm sure there is a simple solution but can't see it at the moment.  Thanks for your help,

Ed

Comment: I can't execute your code.  It says `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument` for the line `model = ARIMA(history, order=1,0,1)` Looks like you missed some parenthesis.

Comment: I suggest you follow this tutorial and then after that, if you can't figure it out post some working code and a specific question: [How to Make Out-of-Sample Forecasts with ARIMA in Python](https://machinelearningmastery.com/make-sample-forecasts-arima-python/)

Comment: Thanks - I'll check out the link and revert back.

Comment: I've looked at that example (thanks again for sending it) but I'm still unsure how I would be able to apply the ARIMA model to the observed test data and produce a one-day out-of-sample forecast.  The examples in the link do not seem to be using train/test data to develop the ARIMA model.

Comment: Thanks again for your help with this.  The final solution that I have adopted involves creating an additional/imaginary value in the test data, continue with my forecast, then take the corresponding forecast to the additional/imaginary value as the prediction post the actual test period.  Not the most eligant solution but does provide me with the solution I need.

Answer (score 1):

Your code to fit the model should not be inside the for loop.

Not sure I understand what you want to do.  If the goal is simply to predict beyond the length of the test data then you can do this:

```
train_size = int(len(X) * 0.66)
train, test = X[0:train_size], X[train_size:]
model = ARIMA(train, order=(1,0,1))
model_fit = model.fit()
test_size = test.shape[0]
forecast_length = test_size + 1
yhat = model_fit.forecast(steps=forecast_length)
```

But if you want to take into account the test data, then you need to re-fit the model to the test data and forecast from there.

```
model = ARIMA(X, order=(1,0,1))
model_fit = model.fit()
forecast_length = 1
yhat = model_fit.forecast(steps=forecast_length)
```